# Field Keyword and Molecular Orbitals--Gaussian 09

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

I am using Gaussian 09 to run calculations. I am applying a 0.1 eV field in the positive Z direction to a molecule. I am also using the %chk keyword so that I may analyze the Molecular Orbitals after I apply the field. Only the HOMO and LUMO show absolutely no change. Am I doing something wrong? Should I use a higher value for the field? I am using #Field=z+36 (did the conversion to hartrees)

Theory wise there should be a change in the orbitals, correct?

To add, I aligned the molecule along the Z axis using a script I wrote.

Comment: Thinking in a classical way, how strong is the force on one electron due the applied external field? And how strong are the coulomb forces between particles?

Comment: I guess I'm just confused because there is work being done on the particles, per the field. So why doesn't that reflect in the HOMO and LUMO?

Comment: You need a field strong enough

Comment: I do not know the field intensity needed in order to get an energy difference large enough, I would expect an energy level splitting

Comment: I'm such an airhead. I forgot to divide by the length of the molecule...

Comment: So did you get the answer? I am having the same doubt. Please explain.